# Simplify conditional expression using C# 6

Tags: c#, c#-6.0

I have the following conditions:

```
Int32 pageSize = query.PageSize == null
    ? _apiSettings.DefaultPageSize
    : (query.PageSize > _apiSettings.PageSizeLimit
        ? _apiSettings.PageSizeLimit
        : query.PageSize.Value);
```

Is it possible, using C# 6, to simplify this expression?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need anything that's new in C# 6 for that. Clamping can be done generally using `Math.Max` and `Math.Min`. Making the clamping optional can be done by passing `int.MinValue` or `int.MaxValue` when no check should be done.

```
var pageSize = Math.Min(
    query.PageSize ?? _apiSettings.DefaultPageSize,
    _apiSettings.PageSizeLimit ?? int.MaxValue);
```

I'm assuming `PageSizeLimit` is nullable here, but if it's not, just take out the `?? int.MaxValue`.

Note that this is not strictly equivalent: it gives different results if `DefaultPageSize > PageSizeLimit`. But given your property names, that seems like a scenario you won't need to support, or if you do need to support it, you *should* limit that to `PageSizeLimit` as well like I do here.

Answer (score 4):

So obviously the statement is quiet complex and I guess you need all the checks in there. Using the ternary operator twice in the same row just makes it unreadable in my opinion.

To make it more readable (and therefore to simplify it in a way) I would just extract the logic as method like this:

```
Int32 pageSize = GetPageSize(query.PageSize);
```

...

```
In32 GetPageSize(Int32 queryPageSize)
{
    if (queryPageSize == null)
        return _apiSettings.DefaultPageSize;

    if (queryPageSize > _apiSettings.PageSizeLimit)
        return _apiSettings.PageSizeLimit;

    return queryPageSize;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No, since that way or another you'd have to check 2 conditions (null check and threshold check). 
Nevertheless, you are able to simplify it that way:

```
Int32 pageSize = 
    query.PageSize == null 
    ? _apiSettings.DefaultPageSize
    : Math.Min(query.PageSize, _apiSettings.PageSizeLimit);
```

Answer (score 0):

One very simple simplification is simply to get rid of the parentheses, and reformat:

```
Int32 pageSize =
    query.PageSize == null ? _apiSettings.DefaultPageSize :
    query.PageSize > _apiSettings.PageSizeLimit ? _apiSettings.PageSizeLimit :
    query.PageSize.Value;
```

In my opinion this is simple and readable enough.